# Minecraft server ops.json

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If I change an op's "level" in the `ops.json` file, will it save their level individually or will it default back to the `server.properties` "op-permission-level"?

Just wanting to make sure before I test it and find out someone I thought I gave a level of 2 instead defaulted back to level 4.

Comment: Should be relatively easy to test, the wiki lists all OP levels required for commands here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#List_and_summary_of_commands

Comment: heck, ok so I was able to set up a private server and test this out.

So if you do go into the ops.json file and change an op's level, it will update the next time they join the server _server doesn't have to restart for this to take effect since it's a .json file_

Comment: That seems like a good thing to write as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After letting curiosity get the best of me, I decided to run a private Minecraft server to test this question, and I've found that you can indeed simply edit the ops.json file and change a user's op permissions level.

For those that are curious as to how that change will take effect; understand that a .json file is pretty much a running script that never stops until the "host" being the server stops, and with knowing that, an op will not be affected until they re-enter the server after the ops.json file is updated.

**TL;DR**
Yes, you can change op levels individually to each user by updating their level in ops.json *just be sure to update the ops.json before they join for it to take effect, also, you don't have to restart the server for the updated ops.json to apply to the server rules*

Comment: JSON files are **not** scripts. They are just text files of a certain format that are read by, in this case, Minecraft. They only store data, like settings.